# Android Downloading Multiple images from Internet

Tags: android, image, download

I am trying to download multiple images from internet(number is big 50+)
I am creating an Ansynch task for each image and start the download and show the downloaded images in a grid. Since I am using the Grid view as soon as i come into the my GridActivity the getView method is called and it starts the Downloading. Now many times the code fails giving a socket error. The algo is -

```
    getView{
            call the Asynch Task
    }
    AsyncTask(){
        start the download
        once download finsishes update the grid view image 
   }
```

Comment: Can you post the error and maybe some simplified source?

Answer (score 1):

AsycTask is good choice have you looked at this [multithreading-for-performance](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html), If not then it is a good tutorial to handle what you're trying accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

I hope that solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Very good, powerful, simple to use library to consider: [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso).